# List Casting in C#

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, covariance

I have the following very simple and (abridged) classes:

```
// IEntry interface
public interface IEntry {
  long Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

// IEntry implementation 
public class Contact : IEntry {
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// DAO Interface
public interface IEntryDao {
  List<IEntry> findUnapproved();
}

// abstract base class 
public abstract class AbstractEntryDao : IEntryDao {
  public virtual List<IEntry> findUnapproved() {
    List<IEntry> entries = new List<IEntry>();
    // ... default load logic
    return entries;
  }
}

// ContactDao implementation 
public class ContactDao : AbstractEntryDao { 
  public override List<IEntry> findUnapproved() {
     List<IEntry> contacts = new List<IEntry>();
     // ... custom load logic for Contact
     return contacts;
  }
}

// sample client code
public void testFindUnapproved() {
  ContactDao contactDao = new ContactDao();
  List<IEntry> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved(); // <--- this line works (but not what I want) 
  List<Contact> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved(); // <--- this does not work (which makes sense)
  List<Contact> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved() as List<Contact>; // <--- this does not work

  // here is how i compensate for this problem... but i do not like this
  List<Contact> list = new List<Contact>();
  foreach (IManageableEntry contact in contacts) {
      list.Add(contact as Contact);
  }
}
```

What I would like is a very short hand way (or possibly using generics in the Dao interface and abstract class)

```
List<Contact> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved(); // <--- can I achieve this using generics in .NET 3.5?
```

Otherwise, what's a clean alternative solution other than the very end of my sample client code that I believe to be a poor practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Contact> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved().Cast<Contact>().ToList();
```

Just remember to add using linq namespace above the file

Comment: When I replace my code with this line, I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.Entry.Contact>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Entry.Contact>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).  Do I need to recast the resulting collection?

Comment: No, It must work, Seems that you need to add another .Tolist() to method chain after .Cast<Contact>(), so it must be Cast<Contact>().ToList()

Comment: Actually there are new concepts introduced in .NET 4 which makes working with Generics lot more easier, it might be helpful if you read it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72467/C-4-0-Covariance-And-Contravariance-In-Generics http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd799517(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx), if `findUnapproved` may return different implementations of `IEntry` and you only want to get `Contact` from the list:

```
List<Contact> contacts = contactDao.findUnapproved().OfType<Contact>().ToList();
```

As far as `OfType` (and `Cast`) return `IEnumerable<T>` you need to call `ToList` to get what you wanted.

Comment: Yep, I was missing the .ToList() there at the end.  Thanks!